# populate Windows 8 "All apps" list

Tags: windows-8

I have an MSI package that creates some shortcuts, playing around with Windows 8 I noticed that on the Start screen it shows only the shortcuts from the top level folder of my application which I create in **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\**. When I hit "All apps" Windows displays and the shortcuts from the sub-folders for other apps (for example VS 2012), but not for mine. Does anyone knows why? What else do I need to do so I can have Windows display shortcuts found in my sub-folder when the user selects "All apps"?

Comment: What did you create your MSI with?

Comment: Advanced Installer, its free for "Simple" project type and trial for the rest. You can get it from here:http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html   However, I also tried to create some shortcuts manually, outside the installer, with no luck. The changes that Microsoft made for Windows Installer in Windows 8 are quite small, with no mentions of changes to its shortcuts support.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.  It appears that there is a problem with the app indexer.  So far I haven't found a way to simply force the search to find my apps without a bit of unneeded effort.  To force search to find your app you can simply pin it to the start menu and then unpin it from the start menu this adds it to your local preferences.

Another indication of what is happening is that, even if a shortcut is deleted, it still shows in the All Apps menu until you do a disk cleanup and delete thumbnails.

I found another oddity.  I have Tortoise Svn installed and anything I put in the start menu folder for that application shows up, but in my Open Office start menu folder the link has to be prepended with "OpenOffice.org " to show up.

Answer (score 2):

I install my shortcut links here:

C:\Users\Randall\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

This works just fine for me. My shortcuts all show up in the Win8 all apps list.

I'm installing in the user's profile so my app can run as a non-admin.